# Determine argument type from template function argument

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, typename

I'm used to C++ templates, and coding for portable code (MSVC, XCode...).
In a simplified form, I wrote a function

```
template <typename T, void (*FUNC)(T, T)>
void ApplyFuncOnBuffer(T* buffer, int count) { /* ... */ }
```

and a caller template code is like

```
template <typename A>
void Process(A val1, A val2) { /* ... */ }

template <typename A>
void ProcessBuffer(A* buffer, int count)
{
    ApplyFuncOnBuffer<A, &Process>(buffer, count);
}
```

That is fine, it compiles and works, but I would like to simplify the invoke from

```
ApplyFuncOnBuffer<A, &Process>(buffer, count);
```

to

```
ApplyFuncOnBuffer<&Process>(buffer, count);
```

Which means finding a way to determine T from FUNC template argument
I searched and tried solutions, but "templatizing" the argument FUNC

```
template <template <typename T> void (*FUNC)(T, T)>
void ApplyFuncOnBuffer(T* buffer, int count) { /* ... */ }
```

MSVC compiler says :

```
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
error C2059: syntax error : '<L_TEMPLATEDECL>'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<end Parse>'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Which globally says the syntax is wrong.

At last, my question is : would anyone know some valid syntax that allows to determine the T type from the FUNC template argument, without having to add it explicitly as a template argument of ApplyFuncOnBuffer ?

Comment: You're looking for a feature that is not yet incorporated in the language, but was already proposed: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html

Comment: Even with a trait do get `T` from `FUNC`, your template would be `template <typename F, F f> void ApplyFuncOnBuffer(extractT<FUNC>* buff, int count)` with `ApplyFuncOnBuffer<decltype(&Process), &Process>(buffer, count);` :/

Comment: Could you pass `FUNC` as argument instead ?

Comment: @Columbo Oh man, *another* different usage of `using`. Know what the status of that paper is?

Comment: @Barry Unfortunately not. I'd email the author.

Answer (score 0):

> anyone know some valid syntax that allows to determine the `T` type from the `FUNC` template argument, without having to add it explicitly as a template argument of `ApplyFuncOnBuffer`?

No such luck. As [Columbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3647361/columbo) points out, there's a proposal that would eventually let you do what you want. But until then, you have three options really:

1. Stick with being verbose:

   ```
   ApplyFuncOnBuffer<A, &Process>(buffer, count);
   ```
2. Write a macro (*shudder*) to pull out `A` for you.

   ```
   #define APPLY(func) get_arg_type_t<func>, func
   ApplyFuncOnBuffer<APPLY(&Process)>(buffer, count);
   ```
3. If possible, take the function pointer as an argument:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   void ApplyFuncOnBuffer(T*, void (*)(T, T), int );

   ApplyFuncOnBuffer(buffer, Process, count);
   ```

Choose your weapon wisely.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.
I will look into passing as an argument.